# node crypto decipher stream throws EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length if stream will be interrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, stream, aes

I have a node.js client which downloads and decrypts an AES encrypted file from another host.

```
var base64 = require('base64-stream');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var aes = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', crypto.createHash('sha256').update(pass).digest('hex'));

// file stream
var file = fs.createWriteStream(params.target);
var base64reader = base64.decode();
response.pipe(base64reader)  // decode base64
        .pipe(aes)              // decrypt
        .pipe(file);            // write in file

// on last data chunk received: file load complete
aes.on('end', function (chunk) {
    if (typeof params.success !== 'undefined')
        params.success();
});
```

If the other host close his connection unexpectedly before finishing the request, the code above throws this error:

```
TypeError: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
    at Decipher.Cipher._flush (crypto.js:262:27)
    at Decipher.eval (_stream_transform.js:130:12)
    at Decipher.g (events.js:187:16)
    at Decipher.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at prefinish (_stream_writable.js:427:12)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:435:7)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:317:3)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:307:7)
    at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:100:5)
    at afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:99:5)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:74:12)
    at Decipher.Cipher._transform (crypto.js:258:3)
    at Decipher.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:179:10)
    at Decipher.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:334:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:743:26)
    at WriteStream.eval (_stream_readable.js:601:7)
```

I tried to add an aes.on('error', function(() {...}); handler but it will not be called. I also tried adding

```
response.on('end', function() { aes.emit('close'); });
response.on('close', function() { aes.emit('close'); });
```

but then aes.on('end', ...); will not be called. Adding aes.emit('end') to this statements make no sense, because this will be also called in case of an error which leads to the error above.

```
response.on('end', function() { aes.emit('end'); aes.emit('close'); });
response.on('close', function() { aes.emit('end'); aes.emit('close'); });
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can catch this error?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in node.js v0.11.9 which is solved in v0.11.13. Then aes.on('error', ...) will be called correctly.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, Toby. Try and use tags with a lot of followers to have more success, even I don't look at the AES tag regularly.

Comment: Wow it sure seems to me that this is still around.  I can find NO way of catching this error when using pipes.